# Подсчёт длины аргумента скрипта

Tags: bash, консоль, shell, zsh

Пишу скрипт, который будет просто принимать аргументы в неограниченном количестве и возвращать самый длинный из них. Сейчас, как видите он просто выдаёт все аргументы. Подскажите, как именно прописать if чтобы проверял и выбирал самый длинный аргумент? И как сделать, чтобы аргументы принимались с дефисом?

```
#!/bin/zsh
for item in "$@";
do
echo "Параметры $item"
done
```

Comment: https://baks.dev/article/terminal/bash-if-else-statement

Comment: я понимаю синтаксис, не пойму как именно написать чтобы выдавал самый длинный аргумент. В массиве понятно было бы, а в "@" как?

Comment: вот вам массив: ```while [ -n "$1" ] do echo "param : $1" shift done``` сможете теперь добавить необходимые вам условия?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/zsh
```

без необходимости лучше не использовать `zsh` для скриптов

> принимать аргументы в неограниченном количестве и возвращать самый
> длинный из них.

один из способов решения задачи:

```
#!/bin/bash

for item in "$@"; do
  items=$items"\n"$item
done

max_item=$(echo -e "$items" |awk '$0!=""{print length($0),NR,$0}' |sort -n |awk 'END{print $2-1}')

echo "Самый длинный аргумент: ${!max_item}"
```

пример работы скрипта:

```
$ ./script.sh dsfdsf df "12345678 1" sdfsd "123456789 2" 44
Самый длинный аргумент: 123456789 2
```

Если длинных аргументов несколько то можно вывести их все

```
#!/bin/bash

for item in "$@"; do
  items=$items"\n"$item
done

ARGS=$(echo -e "$items" |awk '$0!=""{print length($0),NR,$0}' |sort -n)
MAX_LENGTH=$(echo "$ARGS" |awk 'END{print $1}')
echo "$ARGS" |awk -v N=$MAX_LENGTH '$1==N{$1=$2="";print "Самый длинный аргумент "++i":"$0}'
```

пример работы скрипта:

```
$ ./script.sh dsfdsf df "12345678ф 1" sdfsd "123456789 2" 44
Самый длинный аргумент 1:  12345678ф 1
Самый длинный аргумент 2:  123456789 2
```

> И как сделать, чтобы аргументы принимались с дефисом?

посмотри https://devhints.io/bash (раздел **Getting options**), там есть шаблон как принимать параметры с одним(`-`) или двумя дефисами(`--`), кроме того там есть возможность задавать аргументы с параметрами (пример `--arg1=123` и/или `--arg 123`) и без (пример `--arg1`, их еще называют флагами).

Comment: Спасибо большое)) Столько новых слов в командах вижу. У меня просто стандартный поставлен zsh, не думал что между ними принципиальная разница.

Comment: Подскажите, если вводим несколько параметров и каждый из них самый длинный, какое изменение нужно внести, чтобы скрипт выдавал  первый введённый, а не последний, как сейчас?

Comment: @Илья `У меня просто стандартный поставлен zsh, не думал что между ними принципиальная разница.` - как раз таки принципиальной разницы между ними нету, но есть очень много нюансов которые нужно учитывать, поэтому ради переносимости и чтобы меньше забивать голову этими нюансами при скриптовании лучше придерживаться **стандарта**. А `zsh` хорош в _живой_ консоли. `если вводим несколько параметров и каждый из них самый длинный ...` - чуть позже допишу в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуем решить задачу используя **bash**

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

#создаем массив и добавляем в нулевой элемент пустоту
#Дописываем все входящие параметры в массив
#Устанавливаем разделение строк \n, что бы параметры с пробелом не страдали
IFS=$'\n' arr=( "" `printf '%s\n' "$@"` )
#цикл по длине массива
for ((i=0;i<${#arr[@]};i++));do
#Проверяем является ли длинна строки больше максимальной длинны строки
#Если да, то записываем элемент массива в переменную max
    [[ ${#arr[$i]} -gt ${#arr[${max:-0}]} ]] && max=$i
done
echo -e "Параметр: \$$max\nДлина: ${#arr[$max]}\nЗначение: ${arr[$max]}"
```

console:

```
script.sh "fwegwg fwfwef" geger ergherhrtmj
#output> Параметр: $1
#output> Длина: 13
#output> Значение: fwegwg fwfwef
```

Это выведет наиболее длинный переданный параметр в скрипт, остается вопрос, что делать со строками такой же длинны, если они присутствуют в других параметрах

Answer (score 1):

Для сортировки можно использовать массив:

```
#!/bin/bash

for arg in "$@"; {
    N=${#arg}    # передать длинну аргумента в переменную N
    sort[N]=$arg # создать ячейку с номером N в массиве sort
}

echo ${sort[@]:(-1)} # вывести последний элемент массива sort
```

Проверим:

```
$ ./test 1 22 3 44
44
```

Если же необходимо сохранить только первый "самый длинный" аргумент, добавим условие:

```
...
[[ ${sort[N]} ]] || sort[N]=$arg # создать ячейку если её нет
...
```

Проверим:

```
$ ./test 1 22 3 44
22
```